# Vulkan DestroyInstance / DestroyDevice with VK_NULL_HANDLE

Tags: c++, vulkan

I was under the impression you could call Destroy / Free on a NULL handle, and it would be a no-op.

> **2.5.1 Valid Usage**
>
> It is valid to pass VK_NULL_HANDLE to any vkDestroy* or vkFree* command, which will silently ignore these values.

But what happens if you used *vkGetInstanceProcAddr* and *vkGetDeviceProcAddr* to get the function pointers? I'm doing the following:

```
Device::Device(Device&& other) :
    handle(other.handle),
    functions(other.functions)
{
    other.handle = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
}
```

Of course, when the destructor is called for the original device, it passes in a null handle to the device-specific *vkDestroyDevice*.

Currently, this is giving me a read access violation, and I'm not sure whether this is AMD's fault, LunarG's fault, or my fault.

Comment: *2.6.1 in the newest specification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a driver bug.

There is a distinction between dispatchable handles (aka: pointers) and non-dispatchable handles (aka: integers). NDH's are the kind of handles that can store `VK_NULL_HANDLE`.

Notice how `vkDestroyDevice`'s "Valid Usage" section talks about the device possibly being `NULL`, while `vkDestroyCommandBufferPool` talks about the pool possibly being `VK_NULL_HANDLE`. So the specification clearly makes that distinction.

This means that the statement in 2.5.1 is not referring to referring to `vkDestroy*` functions that take dispatchable handles. After all, they cannot assume the value `VK_NULL_HANDLE`.

Of course, `VK_NULL_HANDLE` happens to be defined as 0. And in C++, the integer literal 0 also doubles as a null pointer constant. Which means that this:

```
VkDevice dev = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
```

is perfectly legal. Even though the Vulkan specification doesn't necessitate that this makes sense.

However, all of that is irrelevant. Why? Because `vkDestroyDevice`'s "Valid Usage" section includes this statement:

> - If `device` is not `NULL`, `device` must be a valid `VkDevice` handle

The condition here clearly requires that `device` can indeed be `NULL`. So if an implementation is crashing when you do that, it's a problem with that implementation.

Comment: Along with crashes, there are also validation errors when trying to call `vkDelete*` on `VK_NULL_HANDLE`, with `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation`. ERROR: [OBJTRACK]: Invalid VkImage Object 0x0. ERROR: [OBJTRACK]: Unable to remove obj 0x0. Was it created? Has it already been destroyed?

So it appears this is also a bug in the validation layers (v1.0.8).

Comment: I posted a bug report on the LunarG site, and it has been resolved with the release of 1.0.11.